# Run psql using an input file whilst pg_dump is busy writing to the input file

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql, pg-dump

This is probably a far out idea, but I have fallen in love with Linux/Unix and piping output to input.

The use case is to restore data from a production environment to a development environment as quickly as possible.

I know that one could be syncing / streaming from the production environment, but this is more a question to understand bash / unix commands and getting my psql / pg_dump knowledge up to scratch.

We do not have enough disk space to have a replicated dev instance for each production database, and we need to restore only when there is an issue that needs to be troubleshooted.

Comment: Which over one will get the job done! My idea is to start the psql restore part (runs for hours ) whilts the pg_dump (runs for hours) is busy so that instead 5 hours for pg_dump and 5 hours for psql restore it takes 6 hours in total

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output from `pg_dump` right into `pg_restore`, that should do the trick:

```bash
pg_dump -F c -h prodhost proddb | pg_restore -h devhost --if-exists -c -C -d postgres
```

Comment: I will give this a go! Thanks